# XML Message Listener in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have question regarding XML messages.
Here is my case: 
I am writing Listener which has to listen the Web Sphere Server and get the XML Messages and parse/Filter and create output XML file.

I need some help to proceed:

My Input messages looks like:

```
<content xsi:type=
"ns2:CreateChangeRequest" xmlns:ns2="http://nmd.org/esb/business" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<request>
<enterpriseId>8e08a2d5cff64c53a562ed5898579092</enterpriseId>
<requestedForInfo>
<requestedForEnterpriseId>f8af0af25c86439ea378ed5898579092</requestedForEnterpriseId>
<requestedForClass>Recipient</requestedForClass>
<phenotypeSequenceNumber>1</phenotypeSequenceNumber>
</requestedForInfo>
</request>
```

Comment: input message to where? I think you need to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is an MQ descriptor, right? IBM provides .Net libraries to connect with MQ, although they are a little difficult to find. [Here is the download link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24009961&rs=0&cs=utf-8&context=SSFKSJ&dc=D41F5&loc=en_US&lang=en&cc=US); MQC6.

IBM also has a few classes and Redbooks about integrating MQ and .Net - try [here](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/SG247012.html?Open) for the Redbook and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/dm-dw-dm-0308surange-i.html?S_TACT=104AHW11&S_CMP=LIB) for the class. (registration is required for the class as I remember)

I never had to use C# to talk to MQ. I had to switch to Java and ESQL instead, but I had studied the Redbook some time ago. Some sample code is included, and it seems straightforward enough. Look at the Get method of the MQQueue class.